# Find part of folder name in bash script

Tags: regex, linux, bash, switch-statement

Trying to find a specific part in a folder structure, but I'm having trouble using RegEx within a bash script - [furthermore I don't speak RegEx fluently](http://xkcd.com/208/). I need to know what folder 'type' I passed to the bash script. Depending on the folder 'type' it currently is in it would need to run different actions.

The following example folder structure:

```
/home/usr/media/series/Great.Series.S01E02.Something
/home/usr/media/movies/Some.Movie.Here
/home/usr/media/music/An Album Here
/home/usr/media/music/Another Album
```

The RegExr I played around with, but couldn't find a solution: http://regexr.com/39mk4. I wouldn't know how to do this in bash.

I'm trying to find the name of the folder *below* `media`. So basically I want to create something like this (non-bash pseudocode):

```
$currentFolder = '/home/usr/media/series/Great.Series.S01E02.Something'
//magic, the following would need to be series|movies|music depending on the input path
$currentFolder = 'series'
switch ($currentFolder) {
  case 'series':
    //something
   case 'movies':
    //something else
   case 'music':
    //more
}
```

---

A two part question:

1. How do I `grep` or use `find` or something better to get the particular `currentFolder`?
2. Could I do all that in a smart `case` statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `basename` and `dirname` with `case` statements:

```
currentFolder='/home/usr/media/series/Great.Series.S01E02.Something'
currentFolder=$(basename $(dirname $currentFolder))
case $currentFolder in
    series)
        # Do something
        ;;
    movies)
        # Do something else
        ;;
    music)
        # another
        ;;
    *)
        ;;
esac
```

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @falsetru, basename and dirname are good options. If you insist on using regular expressions I suggest you struggle with sed a while. It is complicated but once learned you can do amazing things with it. Here's a variant:

```
currentFolder='/home/usr/media/series/Great.Series.S01E02.Something'
dn=`dirname $currentFolder | sed 's/\/home\/usr\/media\///'`
case $dn in
    'series') echo "Boring TV";;
    'movies') echo "Who has time?";;
    'music')  echo "Well, Pink Floyd is ok!";;
esac
```

But be careful with how you place spaces! And use no $ in front of the variable name on assignments. Bash has another syntax than Java, C or Python!